# Traefik behind Apache proxy

Tags: apache, docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I would like to ask for some help, I have been working with Traefik for 2-3 months, we created an infrastructure with Docker Swarm, took 4 dedicated servers in our cluster and used Traefik as reverse proxy for the containers with a domain.

A few days ago our IT broke and had to recreate it, we got a virtual machine, which is on a dedicated server and handles bunch of VMs too, and here comes the problem. This VM does not have any public IP address, it is behind an apache proxy which handles all the incoming requests on 80 and forwards to the VM where the Traefik runs.

My problem is that our IT was working with Traefik which was connected directly to the internet with a public IP, but I can not configure Traefik to work with behind this Apache proxy, I always get the minimal error message: 404 page not found.

The VM runs CentOS.

If anybody had the same problem and managed a solution please reply, I hope Traefik can work behind Apache proxy. Maybe we just lack some domain/hostname configuration on this VM but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to share at least your apache virtual host in order to get some help.

Comment: The problem is that I can not get the Apache config, it is handled by another organization.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is in the proxy configuration inside Apache. But without access to the config it's pretty impossible to say for sure

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>  
ServerName host.xy  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://host.xy/  
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *:443>  
ServerName host.xy  
SSLEngine on  
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/host.xy.cert  
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/host.xy.key  
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/host.xy.fullchain  
ProxyPass / http://vm-internall-ip-address/  
ProxyPassReverse / http://vm-internall-ip-address/  
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Try adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` right after the `ProxyPass `directives

Comment: Thanks, we will give it a try.
Another question, so when my VM has the name of its host localhost.localdomain, and we want to use the mentioned example host: host.xy - in the traefik.toml which host should I write and when adding lables to the services in stacks which one should we use for host?

Comment: Done and working!! Thanks for the help, now it is available, another question, what did the ProxyPreserveHost to make it work?

Comment: I'll explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Apache in front of traefik is not forwarding the `Host` header correctly to traefik.

In order to proxy your requests to the correct backend, traefik uses the standard HTTP header `Host` which basically is the hostname that the end user requested (what he typed in his browser).

If you put apache in front of that and add a proxy rule like the following:

```
ProxyPass / x.y.z.w
ProxyPassReverse / x.y.z.w
```

Where `x.y.z.w` is the IP address of traefik, the `Host` header will be rewritten by apache to be `x.y.z.w`.

That means that the original `Host` requested by the user would be lost and traefik would be unable to proxy correctly.

In order to make Apache preserve the `Host` header coming from the client when forwarding calls to a proxy, you need to add the following configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Right after the `ProxyPass` directives.

Comment: Thank you!! It is much more cleaner now! :)

Comment: 3 years later and this answer helped where tons of other searching didn't.  Thank you!